# nepalese citizen travelling from sydney to india

Tags: visas, india, nepali-citizens, australian-residents

I am a Nepalese citizen living in Sydney. I have to travel to India for few days. My question is, do I have to get a visa to travel to India  as im currently living in Sydney? 
cheers!!!

Answer (score 6):

As you are coming from Australia (direct I presume), you only need a valid Nepalese passport to enter India.

If you had planned to enter India from Nepal (and not Australia), you wouldn't even need a passport. Conversely if your plan is to enter India from China, Pakistan, Hong-Kong, Macau and Maldives, you will require a visa.

As per [Bureau of Immigration](https://boi.gov.in/content/nepalese-passengers) (emphasis mine)

> IDENTITY DOCUMENTS REQUIRED FOR NEPALESE CITIZEN :
>
> I. A citizen of Nepal entering India by land or air does not require a passport or Visa for entry in India.
>
> II. A citizen of Nepal while travelling by air between Nepal and India
> is required to be in possession of any of the following identity
> documents to establish his/her identity as a Nepalese citizen:
>
> - Nepalese Passport.
> - Nepalese Citizenship Certificate.
> - Voter’s Identification Card issued by the Election Commission of Nepal.
> - Limited Validity photo-identity certificate issued by Nepalese Missions in India when deemed necessary.
> - For children between age group of 10-18, photo ID issued by the Principal of the School, if accompanied by parents having valid travel
>   documents.  No such document is required for children below the age
>   group of 10 years.
>
> III. **A citizen of Nepal must be in possession of a valid Passport
> while entering/exiting India from/to a place other than Nepal.**
>
> IV. A citizen of Nepal must have a visa for India if he/she is
> entering India from China, Macau, Hong Kong, Pakistan and Maldives.